# can't save contact on device using address book - xcode

Tags: xcode, addressbook, abaddressbook, abperson

I've found a code to save a vcard to the device.
This code works perfect on the simulator, but when trying the code on a device, I don't see the new contact.
The code is:

```
NSString *vCardString = @"BEGIN:VCARD\nVERSION:2.1\nN:Standard11.3,Joe;\nADR:PO Box 555,Suite 55,5555 Any Street,San Diego,CA,92111,USA;;\nEND:VCARD";

    CFDataRef vCardData = (CFDataRef)CFBridgingRetain([vCardString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);  ABAddressBookRef book = ABAddressBookCreate();
    ABRecordRef defaultSource = ABAddressBookCopyDefaultSource(book);
    CFArrayRef vCardPeople = ABPersonCreatePeopleInSourceWithVCardRepresentation(defaultSource, vCardData);
    CFRelease(vCardData);
    for (CFIndex index = 0; index < CFArrayGetCount(vCardPeople); index++) {
        ABRecordRef person = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(vCardPeople, index);
        ABAddressBookAddRecord(book, person, NULL);
        //CFRelease(person);
    }
    CFRelease(vCardPeople);
    CFRelease(defaultSource);
    ABAddressBookSave(book, NULL);
    CFRelease(book);
```

Any idea why?
Another thing, is that I saw in other app on the settings permission to use the address book, maybe thats the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is on iOS 6, you need to ask the user's permission to get access to the address book.

```
ABAddressBookRef ref = ABAddressBookCreate();
ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(ref, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
   if(granted) {
      //Use the address book
   }
});
```

This will bring up the prompt so the user can approve your app.